# How comparator works for objects that are not comparable in python?

Tags: python

I have defined a list as below:

```
list = [1,3,2,[4,5,6]]
```

then defined a comparator method as below:

```
def reverseCom(x,y):
   if(x>y):
        return -1
   elif(x<y):
        return 1
   else:
        return 0
```

Now I have sorted the list using reverseCom:

```
list.sort(reverseCom)
print list
```

> Result : [[4, 5, 6], 3, 2, 1]

Though the element [4, 5, 6] is not comparable with other elements of the list. How its not throwing any error ?

Do you can help me to understand that how sort works with the user defined comparator in python ?

Comment: You don't get errors, because the objects are comparable. That is `list` instances can be compared to `int` instances. Try `[4,5,6] > 3`. Any `list` is always greater than any `int` as far as I remember. That is how comparison methods are defined in `list`.

Answer (score 10):

This is a Python 2 quirk. In Python 2, numeric and non numeric values are comparable, and numeric values are always considered to be less than the value of container objects:

```
>>> 1 < [1]
True
>>> 1 < [2]
True
>>> 1558 < [1]
True
>>> 1 < {}
True
```

when comparing two containers values of different types, on the other hand, it is the *name of their type* that is taken into consideration:

```
>>> () < []
False
>>> 'tuple' < 'list'
False

>>> {} < []
True
>>> 'dict' < 'list'
True
```

This feature, however, has been dropped in Python 3, which made numeric and non-numeric values no longer comparable:

```
>>> 1 < [1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: int() < list()
```

**EDIT:** this next explanation is fully experimentation-based, and I couldn't find sound documentation to back it up. If any one does find it, I'd be glad to read through it.

It appears Python 2 has even more rules when it comes to comparison of user-defined objects/non-container objects.

In this case it appears that numeric values are always *greater* than non-numeric non-container values.

```
>>> class A: pass
...
>>> a = A()
>>> 1 > a
True
>>> 2.7 > a
True
```

Now, when comparing two objects of different, non-numeric, non-container types, it seems that it is their *address* that is taken into account:

```
>>> class A: pass
...
>>> class B: pass
...
>>> a = A()
>>> a
<__main__.A instance at 0x0000000002265348>
>>> b = B()
>>> b
<__main__.B instance at 0x0000000002265048>
>>> a < b
False
>>> b < a
True
```

Which is really bananas, if you ask me.

Of course, all that can be changed around if you care to override the `__lt__()` and `__gt__()` methods inside your class definition, which determine the standard behavior of the `<` and `>` operators.

Further documentation on how these methods operate can be [found here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html).

**Bottomline:** avoid comparison between different types as much as you can. The result is really unpredictable, unintuitive and not all that well documented. Also, use Python 3 whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your comparator actually works, i.e., does not throw any error:

```
In [9]: reverseCom([4,5,6],1)
Out[9]: -1

In [10]: reverseCom([4,5,6],2)
Out[10]: -1

In [11]: reverseCom([4,5,6],3)
Out[11]: -1
```

The reason why it works is, `list` instances always bigger than `int` instances:

```
In [12]: [1,2,3] > 5
Out[12]: True

In [13]: ['hello'] > 5
Out[13]: True

In [14]: [] > -1
Out[14]: True
```

Comment: @Eli thanks for your reply ,I am very new to python .Can you please help me to understand how comparison works among instances. ` class A: pass `. `a = A()    print a>10  --> false `. print A>10  --> true  and print " " >10000000000000000000 --> true`.

Comment: @Oori I updated my answer with more examples and information on how those crazy Python 2 comparisons work. Please take a look at it, it might solve some of your problems.